JS dblclick event wont get added
I want to add the dbclick event listener to an element, but it doesnt work.
There is no error but the event listener doesnt show up and doesnt work.



const windowHeader = document.createElement("div");
windowHeader.classList.add("windowheader");
windowHeader.ondblclick = function() {
  alert("test");
};
window.appendChild(windowHeader);



It works fine on other element.
It seems to only work on elements which are in the html file and not js generated.
Im new to JS, please help me.

document.body.appendChild(windowHeader) - your console will tell you window.appendChild does not exist

Also you should probably give the header some content, otherwise it will have by default 0 pixels in height and thus will be hard to click on.

maybe append the element to the document first and then add the event listener

And as a note, double-click is generally considered by designers to be a bad idea for web interfaces.

@mplungjan It does, i just didnt show the entire code. If you want I can add the rest, but believe its unnecessary.

@Pointy the header has content, I just didnt add the entire code.

@mplungjan but i want the windowHeader to be a child of the window element. Or do the event listeners dont work for child elements?

If you change window.appendChild(windowHeader); to document.body.appendChild(windowHeader) it works. I can prove this

@ChrisG didnt work. but ty

difference-between-document-addeventlistener-and-window-addeventlistener

RTM

windowHeader.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {

@ChrisG does not change the lack of appendChild on window - it is in functionality the same as ondblclick

window in my case is a div element that i made. sry if that wasnt clear. Didnt know there was something else called window. I renamed the div to avoid conflicts but it still doesnt work.

window is not a reserved word but should not be used since in a browser it is a very important global object. Here is a version that adds the windowheader to a container div. It still works. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rmLwdqun/

@JoJjjo157 Please click [edit], then scroll down to the "edit above snippet", click it and add RELEVANT HTML, CSS and JavaScript to make a [mcve]

You need to use
document.body.appendChild(windowHeader) to add the windowheader to the page - your console will tell you window.appendChild does not exist.
More information:
Difference between document.addEventListener and window.addEventListener?
Some events you can trigger on the global window object:

DOMContentLoaded, load, unload, beforeunload, resize, scroll, error, focus, blur, popstate, hashchange, orientationchange

Some events you can change on the document object:

DOMContentLoaded, click, keydown, keyup, keypress, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, mousedown, mouseup, change, submit, focus and blur, input

You commented:

window in my case is a div element that i made. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Didn't know there was something else called window. I renamed the div to avoid conflicts

If you have a container, name it something else than window which is not a reserved word but should not be used since in a browser it is a very important global object:


const container = document.getElementById('container');
const windowHeader = document.createElement("div");
windowHeader.textContent = 'Click'
windowHeader.classList.add("windowheader");
windowHeader.addEventListener('dblclick', () => { alert("test"); }); // same as yours but more modern
//windowHeader.ondblclick = function() { alert("test"); };
container.appendChild(windowHeader); // works
<div id="container"></div>




it doesnt work for me. Could other listeners break the dblclick listeners? But thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

As you can see it works here, so you need to show more code for us to help you.

For example clicking a submit button  or clicking an A HREF might reload the page and that would break the dblclick
